# How can we access the files in the Data Folder when we publish the Vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I have added some files that I need to be downloaded to the `Application` start up path. So I set `Build Action` as content now the files have been copied some where

```
C:\Documents and Settings\TestUser.ANNAM\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\Data\HVDRBMY5.8AA\858AT9VM.TNP\test..tion_2d7cfc137d9c2c74_0001.0013_432bd4561850d290\Data
```

How can access file from the application. My problem since it is a dynamic path will it be same folder count so that we can use like `..\..\Data\` Some think like this

Answer (score 0):

Application.UserAppDataPath gets the path for the application data of a user.

Application.StartupPath gives you the path for the executable file that started the application, not including the executable name.

Starting with one of these, you should be able to use System.IO to manipulate the paths until you get the folder where your data files are.